# How to enable copy-paste of several cells in a switch statement?

Tags: excel, vba, input, copy-paste

the presented code snippet does automatically add a comment to cells with a certain value inside. It works for multiple inputs, so e.g. if I drag the green frame from one cell over several further cells. Furthermore, it works for copy-pasting one cell (for this I implemented the error handling). If a cell is empty, the comment is automatically removed.

However, if I copy several cells with a comment and then paste it, I receive a runtime error 1004. The reason for the problem seems to be connected to the fact, that Excel, when you copy something deletes the comment and then automatically adds it into the new cell when you paste it. So in my case, 2 comments are added at once to the same cell, which is probably why the error occurs. At least, that's my guess.

Does somebody know, how to solve this? Is my explanation right?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        On Error GoTo AVOID_ERROR_WHEN_COPY_PASTING
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case Is = "A": cell.AddComment ("some comment")
            Case Is = "B": cell.AddComment ("some comment")
            Case Is = "C": cell.AddComment ("some comment")
            Case Is = "": cell.ClearComments
        End Select

        AVOID_ERROR_WHEN_COPY_PASTING:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: the respective case in the statement. So in case the user copies several cells with an "A", then the line with this case throws it

Comment: have you tried removing the existing comment in `cell` before you add another one?

Comment: you mean in the vba-code or manually? Removing manually would not be an option and my problem is exactly that I don't have an understanding on how to implement a solution into the code, that would do this

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't when a comment already existed?  You cannot have multiple comments.

Comment: If you add `Cell.Comment.Delete` above your `Select` line you can replace the comment if A,B or C and no need for the last case.

Comment: @DarrellH: I am not sure, what exactly you mean. My problem case is, that if I copy several cells at the same time and they contain a content relevant for this macro and then I paste those cells into other empty cells, Excel throws an error.

Comment: @DarrellH: thanks for the suggestion, but it throws immediately a runtime error 91

Comment: Try this line in place of the delete, a one line `If..Then`, `If Not cell.Comment Is Nothing Then cell.Comment.Delete`.  This will replace the comment if one exists and add if not.

Comment: @DarrellH Thank you very much! This is the solution to my problem :)